# How can I re-create a table's contents with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to refresh the contents in my Table dynamically. This code here only initiates but does not reload the table.

Contents are stored in "data" object and its values come from a rest call. This works without any problem.

The problem I am having is when I load a different 'data' myDataGrid() function does not work for the second time. How can I refresh it? Should I destroy the object somehow?

This is from the main js code:

```
$('#DataTables_Table_1_wrapper').html("");

$('table[data-table-name="dt-testCells"]').myDataGrid({
    'aoColumns': cols,
    'aaData': data
});
```

Creation of the table:

```
MyDataGrid.prototype = {

constructor: MyDataGrid,

init: function(type, element, options) {
  this.type = type;
  this.$element = $(element);
  this.name = this.$element.data('table-name');
  this.settings = this.getOptions(options);

  this.createTable(options);
},
createTable: function(options) {
  // Init the datatable
  this.$table = this.$element.dataTable(this.settings);

  // Row Selection
  this.$table.on('click', 'tbody tr', $.proxy(this.clicked, this));

}
```

Comment: I see you're using DataTables (you didn't mention it although it's a major point), it's made for ajax calls and table refresh. Check out ajax sourced data from the documentation : http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: What isn't working? There is nothing shown regarding loading new data

Comment: @charlietfl data is loaded correctly and it is in the 'data' object. It creates the table correctly for the first time. But not the second time even though data object is loaded correctly. My theory is it doesn't go inside of myDataGrid({}) for the second, third etc. time.

Comment: @JeremyThille I will be checking, thanks.